# JPA with SequenceGenerator and GeneratedValue

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a code which uses JPA annotations to generate DB primary key.A DB sequence is used to generate the PK.Am using Oracle DB

```
@Id
@Column(name = "rec_id", scale = 0)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "RecIdSequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "RecIdSequence", sequenceName = "P_REC_ID_SEQUENCE")
public Long getRecordId() {
    return outboundPackageRecordId;
}
```

Now my understanding of this is: sequence id returned by DB sequencer is used as rec_id.
IS this correct?

DOC says:

> The Sequence Strategy
>       The sequence strategy consists of two parts - defining a named sequence and using the named sequence in one or more fields in one or
>   more classes. The @SequenceGenerator annotation is used to define a
>   sequence and accepts a name, an initial value (the default is 1) and
>   an allocation size (the default is 50). A sequence is global to the
>   application and can be used by one or more fields in one or more
>   classes. The SEQUENCE strategy is used in the @GeneratedValue
>   annotation to attach the given field to the previously defined named
>   sequence:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100) // Define a sequence - might also be in another class:
public class EntityWithSequenceId {
    // Use the sequence that is defined above:
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
    @Id long id;
}
```

> Unlike AUTO and IDENTITY, the SEQUENCE strategy generates an automatic
>   value as soon as a new entity object is persisted (i.e. before
>   commit). This may be useful when the primary key value is needed
>   earlier. To minimize round trips to the database server, IDs are
>   allocated in groups. The number of IDs in each allocation is specified
>   by the allocationSize attribute. It is possible that some of the IDs
>   in a given allocation will not be used. Therefore, this strategy does
>   not guarantee there will be no gaps in sequence values.

Answer (score 2):

Use  generation type as AUTO instead SEQUENCE on primary key column.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="generator", sequenceName="DB_SEQ_NAME")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will use the next value from your sequence `P_REC_ID_SEQUENCE`.

This also depends upon what database you're using. You can define Sequences in `Postgres` but not `MySQL`.

If you are using `MYSQL` then you can use `Auto-Incremement` but you will not need to define the sequence .

If you're using `ORACLE` database you define sequence as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE emp_sequence
      INCREMENT BY 1
      START WITH 1
```

Now, if the current sequence value is 100 then the next one will be 101. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Makky.We are using oracle DB. Also by next value u mean value retuned by P_REC_ID_SEQUENCE right?

Comment: Yes. the next value returned from your P_REC_ID_SEQUENCE.